# Access event of GestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, avalonia

I am trying to implement a GestureRecognizer on a Border but i can't access any event.
How do i access the event or what other possibilities do i have?

```
<Border Width="500"
    Height="500"
    Margin="5"
    Name="pullBorder">
    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <PullGestureRecognizer PullDirection="LeftToRight"></PullGestureRecognizer>
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```